# Steps in Proof of Convolution Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a proof of the [Convolution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) and don't understand this part:

$$\int |f(z)|\int |g(z-x)| \, dx \, dz = \int|f(z)|\|g\|_1$$

Why does $\int |g(z-x)|dx = \|g\|_1$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|g(z-x)|\,dx.$$
Do a substitution: $u = z-x$ and $du=-dx$.

You get
$$
\int_\infty^{-\infty} |g(u)| \, (-du).
$$